# How to parse ZonedDateTime with default zone?

Tags: java, date, java-8, java-time

How to parse `ZoneDateTime` from string that doesn't contain `zone` and others fields?

Here is test in Spock to reproduce:

```
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

import java.time.ZoneId
import java.time.ZoneOffset
import java.time.ZonedDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

@Unroll
class ZonedDateTimeParsingSpec extends Specification {
    def "DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME parsing incomplete date: #value #expected"() {
        expect:
        ZonedDateTime.parse(value, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME) == expected
        where:
        value                           | expected
        '2014-04-23T04:30:45.123Z'      | ZonedDateTime.of(2014, 4, 23, 4, 30, 45, 123_000_000, ZoneOffset.UTC)
        '2014-04-23T04:30:45.123+01:00' | ZonedDateTime.of(2014, 4, 23, 4, 30, 45, 123_000_000, ZoneOffset.ofHours(1))
        '2014-04-23T04:30:45.123'       | ZonedDateTime.of(2014, 4, 23, 4, 30, 45, 123_000_000, ZoneId.systemDefault())
        '2014-04-23T04:30'              | ZonedDateTime.of(2014, 4, 23, 4, 30, 0, 0, ZoneId.systemDefault())
        '2014-04-23'                    | ZonedDateTime.of(2014, 4, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.systemDefault())
    }
}
```

First two test passed, all others failed with DateTimeParseException:

- '2014-04-23T04:30:45.123' could not be parsed at index 23
- '2014-04-23T04:30' could not be parsed at index 16
- '2014-04-23' could not be parsed at index 10

How can I parse incomplete dates with time and zone setted to default?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since the `ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME` formatter expects zone or offset information, parsing fails.
You'll have to make a `DateTimeFormatter` that has optional parts for both the zone information and the time part.
It's not too hard reverse engineering the `ZonedDateTimeFormatter` and adding optional tags.

Then you parse the `String` using the `parseBest()` method of the formatter. Then, for suboptimal parse results you can create the `ZonedDateTime` using any default you want.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .append(ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
        .optionalStart()           // time made optional
        .appendLiteral('T')
        .append(ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
        .optionalStart()           // zone and offset made optional
        .appendOffsetId()
        .optionalStart()
        .appendLiteral('[')
        .parseCaseSensitive()
        .appendZoneRegionId()
        .appendLiteral(']')
        .optionalEnd()
        .optionalEnd()
        .optionalEnd()
        .toFormatter();

TemporalAccessor temporalAccessor = formatter.parseBest(value, ZonedDateTime::from, LocalDateTime::from, LocalDate::from);
if (temporalAccessor instanceof ZonedDateTime) {
    return ((ZonedDateTime) temporalAccessor);
}
if (temporalAccessor instanceof LocalDateTime) {
    return ((LocalDateTime) temporalAccessor).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
}
return ((LocalDate) temporalAccessor).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Comment: Thanks, it's looks better, but doesn't solve a problem:
<pre>
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain ZoneId from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2014-04-23T04:30:45.123 of type java.time.format.Parsed
</pre>

So, it fails again because I can't set Default timezone for parser.
Same thing for other parts, for examle date.
For example, how can parse a string like '23:45' to ZonedDateTime with current date and system time zone?

Comment: It ran fine using java 8u25 for all 5 of the example string in the question. So, not sure what your problem is.

Comment: problem is that I would like to get ZonedDateTime insted of LocalDateTime

Comment: But my code returns a `ZonedDateTime` in all cases : all three return statments return a `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: Aha, yes, you right, it works, and thanks I will use it :) But anyway, I would prefer to have some more obvious and simple way to define format.
Unfortunately as I see it JavaTime doesn't provide it currently

Comment: You could use a pattern to create the formatter using the `ofPattern()` method. In a pattern you mark optional parts with square brackets

Answer (score 19):

The formatter has a `withZone()` [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withZone-java.time.ZoneId-) that can be called to provide the missing time-zone.

```
ZonedDateTime.parse(
    value,
    DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME.withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()))
```

Bear in mind that there was a bug, so you need 8u20 or later for it to work fully.

Comment: The method `withZone()` always overrides zone even if it contains in string

Comment: @stokito : the problem occurs on strings that have no zone information to be parsed.

Comment: @bowmore the problem is that I need "default or preferred time zone" instead of overriding it