# Java 8 Time API - ZonedDateTime - specify default ZoneId when parsing

Tags: java, timezone, java-time, datetime-parsing, zoneddatetime

I am trying to write a generic method to return a `ZonedDateTime` given a date as `String` and its format.

How do we make `ZonedDateTime` to use the default `ZoneId` if it is not specified in the date `String`?

It can be done with `java.util.Calendar`, but I want to use the Java 8 time API.

[This question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293994/how-to-parse-zoneddatetime-with-default-zone) is using a fixed time zone. I am specifying the format as an argument. Both the date and its format are `String` arguments. More generic.

Code and output below:

```
public class DateUtil {
    /** Convert a given String to ZonedDateTime. Use default Zone in string does not have zone.  */
    public ZonedDateTime parseToZonedDateTime(String date, String dateFormat) {
        //use java.time from java 8
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat);
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
        return zonedDateTime;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DateUtil dateUtil = new DateUtil();
        System.out.println(dateUtil.parseToZonedDateTime("2017-09-14 15:00:00+0530", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"));
        System.out.println(dateUtil.parseToZonedDateTime("2017-09-14 15:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    }
}
```

Output

```
2017-09-14T15:00+05:30
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017-09-14 15:00:00' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2017-09-14T15:00 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1920)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1855)
    at java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.java:597)
    at com.nam.sfmerchstorefhs.util.DateUtil.parseToZonedDateTime(DateUtil.java:81)
    at com.nam.sfmerchstorefhs.util.DateUtil.main(DateUtil.java:97)
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2017-09-14T15:00 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.ZonedDateTime.from(ZonedDateTime.java:565)
    at java.time.format.Parsed.query(Parsed.java:226)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain ZoneId from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2017-09-14T15:00 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.ZoneId.from(ZoneId.java:466)
    at java.time.ZonedDateTime.from(ZonedDateTime.java:553)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse ZonedDateTime with default zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293994/how-to-parse-zoneddatetime-with-default-zone)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replies. Very helpful. Unfortunately, I can accept only one answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A `ZonedDateTime` needs a timezone or an offset to be built, and the second input doesn't have it. (It contains only a date and time).

So you need to check if it's possible to build a `ZonedDateTime`, and if it's not, you'll have to choose an arbitrary zone for it (**as the input has no indication about what's the timezone being used, you must choose one to be used**).

One alternative is to first try to create a `ZonedDateTime` and if it's not possible, then create a `LocalDateTime` and convert it to a timezone:

```
public ZonedDateTime parseToZonedDateTime(String date, String dateFormat) {
    // use java.time from java 8
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat);
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = null;
    try {
        zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
    } catch (DateTimeException e) {
        // couldn't parse to a ZoneDateTime, try LocalDateTime
        LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter);

        // convert to a timezone
        zonedDateTime = dt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    }
    return zonedDateTime;
}
```

In the code above, I'm using `ZoneId.systemDefault()`, which gets the **JVM default timezone**, but this [can  be changed without notice, even at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45797132/7605325), so it's better to always make it explicit which one you're using.

The API uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `America/Sao_Paulo` or `Europe/Berlin`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `CST` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407231/7605325).

You can get a list of available timezones (and choose the one that fits best your system) by calling `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.

If you want to use a specific timezone, just use `ZoneId.of("America/New_York")` (or any other valid name returned by `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`, New York is just an example) instead of `ZoneId.systemDefault()`.

---

Another alternative is to use [`parseBest()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parseBest-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.temporal.TemporalQuery...-), that tries to create a suitable date object (using a list of `TemporalQuery`'s) until it creates the type you want:

```
public ZonedDateTime parseToZonedDateTime(String date, String dateFormat) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat);

    // try to create a ZonedDateTime, if it fails, try LocalDateTime
    TemporalAccessor parsed = formatter.parseBest(date, ZonedDateTime::from, LocalDateTime::from);

    // if it's a ZonedDateTime, return it
    if (parsed instanceof ZonedDateTime) {
        return (ZonedDateTime) parsed;
    }
    if (parsed instanceof LocalDateTime) {
        // convert LocalDateTime to JVM default timezone
        LocalDateTime dt = (LocalDateTime) parsed;
        return dt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    }

    // if it can't be parsed, return null or throw exception?
    return null;
}
```

In this case, I just used `ZonedDateTime::from` and `LocalDateTime::from`, so the formatter will try to first create a `ZonedDateTime`, and if it's not possible, then it tries to create a `LocalDateTime`.

Then I check what was the type returned and do the actions accordingly.
You can add as many types you want (all main types, such as `LocalDate`, `LocalTime`, `OffsetDateTime` and so on, have a `from` method that works with `parseBest` - you can also [create your own custom `TemporalQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/queries.html) if you want, but I think the built-in methods are enough for this case).

---

## Daylight Saving Time

When converting a `LocalDateTime` to a `ZonedDateTime` using the `atZone()` method, there are some tricky cases regarding [Daylight Saving Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/) (DST).

I'm going to use the timezone I live in (`America/Sao_Paulo`) as example, but this can happen at any timezone with DST.

In São Paulo, DST started at October 16<sup>th</sup> 2016: at midnight, clocks shifted 1 hour **forward** from midnight to 1 AM (and the offset changes from `-03:00` to `-02:00`). So all local times between 00:00 and 00:59 didn't exist in this timezone (you can also think that clocks changed from 23:59:59.999999999 directly to 01:00). If I create a local date in this interval, it's adjusted to the next valid moment:

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo");

// October 16th 2016 at midnight, DST started in Sao Paulo
LocalDateTime d = LocalDateTime.of(2016, 10, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0);
ZonedDateTime z = d.atZone(zone);
System.out.println(z);// adjusted to 2017-10-15T01:00-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]
```

When DST ends: in February 19<sup>th</sup> 2017 at midnight, clocks shifted **back** 1 hour, from midnight to 23 PM of **18<sup>th</sup>** (and the offset changes from `-02:00` to `-03:00`). So all local times from 23:00 to 23:59 existed **twice** (in both offsets: `-03:00` and `-02:00`), and you must decide which one you want.
By default, it uses the offset before DST ends, but you can use the `withLaterOffsetAtOverlap()` method to get the offset after DST ends:

```
// February 19th 2017 at midnight, DST ends in Sao Paulo
// local times from 23:00 to 23:59 at 18th exist twice
LocalDateTime d = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 2, 18, 23, 0, 0, 0);
// by default, it gets the offset before DST ends
ZonedDateTime beforeDST = d.atZone(zone);
System.out.println(beforeDST); // before DST end: 2018-02-17T23:00-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]

// get the offset after DST ends
ZonedDateTime afterDST = beforeDST.withLaterOffsetAtOverlap();
System.out.println(afterDST); // after DST end: 2018-02-17T23:00-03:00[America/Sao_Paulo]
```

Note that the dates before and after DST ends have different offsets (`-02:00` and `-03:00`). If you're working with a timezone that has DST, keep in mind that those corner-cases can happen.

Answer (score 5):

There are next to no defaults in `java.time` library, which is mostly a good thing - what you're seeing is what you get, period.

I would suggest that if your date string doesn't contain Zone - it is a `LocalDateTime`, and can't be a `ZonedDateTime`, which is the meaning of exception you're getting (even if verbiage suffered due to overly flexible code structure).

My main suggestion is to parse into local date time if you know that pattern has no Zone information.

However, if you really must, here is another way to do what you want (an alternative solution that does not use exceptions for controlling the flow):

```
TemporalAccessor parsed = f.parse(string);
if (parsed.query(TemporalQueries.zone()) == null) {
  parsed = f.withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).parse(string);
}
return ZonedDateTime.from(parsed);
```

Here we use intermediate parsing result to determine if the string contained Zone information, and if not, we parse again (using same string, but different printer-parser) so that it will contain a zone this time.

Alternatively, you can make this class, which will save you from parsing second time and *should* allow you parse zoned date time, assuming all other fields are there:

```
class TemporalWithZone implements TemporalAccessor {
  private final ZoneId zone;
  private final TemporalAccessor delegate;
  public TemporalWithZone(TemporalAccessor delegate, ZoneId zone) {
    this.delegate = requireNonNull(delegate);
    this.zone = requireNonNull(zone);
  }

  <delegate methods: isSupported(TemporalField), range(TemporalField), getLong(TemporalField)>

  public <R> R query(TemporalQuery<R> query) {
    if (query == TemporalQueries.zone() || query == TemporalQueries.zoneId()) {
      return (R) zone;
    }
    return delegate.query(query);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As per Java 8 ZonedDateTime implementation, **You can not parse date without zone in ZonedDateTime.**

To cater given problem you must have to put try catch in case any exception it will consider default time zone.

Please find revised program as below:

```
public class DateUtil {
     /** Convert a given String to ZonedDateTime. Use default Zone in string does not have zone.  */
    public ZonedDateTime parseToZonedDateTime(String date, String dateFormat) {
        //use java.time from java 8
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat);
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = null;
        try {
            zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
        } catch (DateTimeException e) {
            // If date doesn't contains Zone then parse with LocalDateTime 
            LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
            zonedDateTime = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        }
        return zonedDateTime;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DateUtil dateUtil = new DateUtil();
        System.out.println(dateUtil.parseToZonedDateTime("2017-09-14 15:00:00+0530", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"));
        System.out.println(dateUtil.parseToZonedDateTime("2017-09-14 15:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    }
}
```

You case refer http://www.codenuclear.com/java-8-date-time-intro for more details on upcoming java features

Answer (score 2):

The `ZoneId` can be specified by using the withZone method in the `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat).withZone("+0530");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add a default value in a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` if there is no `OFFSET_SECOND`:

---

EDIT: To get the system's default `ZoneOffset` you have to apply the `ZoneRules` to the current `Instant`. The result looks like this:

```
class DateUtil {
  public ZonedDateTime parseToZonedDateTime(String date, String dateFormat) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat);
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
    ZoneOffset defaultOffset =  ZoneId.systemDefault().getRules().getOffset(localDateTime);
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(formatter)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, defaultOffset.getTotalSeconds())
            .toFormatter();
    return ZonedDateTime.parse(date, dateTimeFormatter);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
2017-09-14T15:00+05:30
2017-09-14T15:00+02:00
```

Comment: There's a tricky case to use the offset for `Instant.now()` regarding Daylight Saving Time. Example: in my JVM, the default zone is `America/Sao_Paulo`. During winter offset is -03:00 and during DST (that starts in October) the offset is -02:00. If I call your method with params `"2017-11-14 15:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`, it'll get a date in November 11st at 15:00 and with current offset (-03:00), but the correct (IMO) should be the offset valid in the local date that corresponds to the input (in this case, in November, when it's already DST, so offset should be -02:00).

Comment: Then have a look in the API and choose the right method: [`ZoneRules::getOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#getOffset-java.time.Instant-) vs. [`ZoneRules::getStandardOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#getStandardOffset-java.time.Instant-). The OP wasn't that specific.

Answer (score -1):

Just copying this solution from a project I have:

```
formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat).withZone(ZONE_UTC);
```

Once the formatter is compiled, you can call `withZone(ZoneId)` to create a new formatter with a set timezone.

Comment: This will ignore the offset +0530 in the first input

Comment: Then try OffsetDateTime, because Zoned requires knowing zone rules.

Comment: Well, OP is asking for `ZonedDateTime` and default timezone (not UTC).